# CsvHelper ignoring values

Tags: c#, csvhelper

In a source file I have sometimes hyphens for double fields sometimes

```
448,218|7,948,218|-|448,218|-
```

I wrote a type converter to handle this.

```
public class HyphenToZeroConverter : ITypeConverter
{
    public string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (text == "-")
        {
            return 0.0;
        }
        return double.Parse(text, NumberStyles.AllowParentheses |
                                  NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
                                  NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
    }
}
```

But the conversion is not working `Message=The conversion cannot be performed.Text:-`

Also the number styles do not  work as I am getting exception for thousand separator and parentheses for negative numbers. This happens even if I am not using any type converter.

Can you please help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see what text contains when you are calling the method, but to do double.parse, you need to make sure to strip out any characters from the text that aren't a number, like

```
text = text.Replace('|', String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by Josh Close - the author of CsvHelper

[Github issue](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1060)